# Change "Email" label based on product category in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display a different "Email label" on the checkout page for a specific category.

For example: 
I'm selling Gift Cards on the site, so I would like to rename the "Email" field, to "Recipient Email", but this specific label should only be visible for the "Gifts" product category.

I couldn't find any WooCommerce functions for this particular solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** The following will change the billing email label if "Gift" product category is in cart:

```
// Change billing email label if "Gift" product category is in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_billing_email_label' );
function change_billing_email_label($fields){
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if( has_term( "Gifts", "product_cat", $cart_item["product_id"] ) ){
            $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = __("Recipient Email", "woocommerce");
            break;
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "LoicTheAztec".

I just had to change the following line of code, from his code

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() => $cart_item) {
```

with this one

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```